# Does storing object / JSON data in chunks improve performance in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I have an application API that is written in Node.JS and uses MongoDB for a database. Part of this system is a messaging service, consisting of 'servers', which have 'channels', similar to the structure of Discord.

Each channel stores an array of references, which corresponds to messages.
This is so that way it's not all one monolithic array of objects. My question is, will storing this array in chunks (for example, by date) improve read/write performance on the database?

I assume it would improve memory usage, which is important for this project, but I don't know much about MongoDB performance and speed.

If I formatted this wrong I'm greatly sorry, I don't normally use StackOverflow so I don't really know much about the formatting rules beyond the basics.

Comment: The question is, do you _need_ to embed an array of message ids in the channel? What does that get you? It looks like this design _forces_ you to touch the channel every time a new message is added, which is very much the opposite of "improve write performance".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My plan was to store the messages themselves in a separate database, to avoid the unbounded array issue that I've seen information about. I was working under the assumption that you should avoid large arrays of objects (like the messages) in this case. As I said, I'm not experienced with this kind of thing, so I'm open to changes.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, don't store even the array of ids, not in chunks, not at all. Instead, each message will have a `channel_id`.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. If I want to query for messages in a channel, wouldn't I need to query every single message?

Comment: Your data structures need to be supporting the important operations/queries on it. Identifying these queries and the data relationships is important for proper data design.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the information.